# how do i add multiple models in one-to-many field in Django Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

*I want to pass gamingpc and pcComponent on OrderItem item field so I can add one of them in item field*

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
            user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
            item = models.ForeignKey(
                gamingpc, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
            product = models.ForeignKey(
                PcComponent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: You can use a `GenericForeignKey` to point to multiple models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Answer (score 0):

you must use [content-type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) for this situation .

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
            user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            content_object = GenericForeignKey()
            object_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
            content_type = models.ForeignKey(
                ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,
                limit_choices_to=(models.Q(model__in=['PcComponent', 'gamingpc']))
```